# Copy complete CSV structure with Data to Datatable

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I have to copy complete CSV file data with its structure without writing long codes.
I have made it using CSV to Access Datatable but having error while using same code for SQL Datatase.

My Code for CSV to Access Datatable;

```vb
Try

            Dim OleDbCnn As New OleDbConnection
            OleDbCnn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\menifestogo.mdb"
            OleDbCnn.Open()
            Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * INTO [TransactionsDetails] FROM [Text;Database=d:\;Hdr=No].[csvfile.csv]", OleDbCnn)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            OleDbCnn.Close()

            MsgBox("Success..")

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

My Code for CSV to SQL Database

```vb
Try

            Dim OleDbCnn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
            OleDbCnn.ConnectionString = "Server=DESKTOP-AS3NIDD\SQLEXPRESS; DataBase=dbS; Integrated Security=SSPI"
            OleDbCnn.Open()
            Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT * INTO [TransactionsDetails] FROM [Text;Database=d:\;Hdr=No].[csvfile.csv]", OleDbCnn)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            OleDbCnn.Close()

            MsgBox("Success..")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

Getting Error:

> Invalid object name 'Text;Database=d:\;Hdr=No.csvfile.csv'

Comment: Its clear that there is an issue with the file name.  As to how to resolve I am not sure.  Have you tried it with removeing the ```;Hdr=No.'```?

Answer (score 0):

Frankly I'll be amazed if SQLServer can parse `[Text;Database=d:\;Hdr=No].[csvfile.csv]` and understand it has to use the Jet driver to access the CSV - Access probably works because you're already using the Jet driver and it'll be able to understand that that text is a way of accessing a file in a folder somewhere. Access/Jet and SQLServer are considerably different

Bulk loading a CSV into SQLServer by issuing a single SQL statement looks more like:

```
BULK INSERT Sales.Orders
FROM '\\SystemX\DiskZ\Sales\data\orders.csv'
WITH ( FORMAT='CSV');
```

Boatload of options [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

If you want to create a new table, something more like this should work

```
SELECT *
INTO YOUR_NEW_TABLE
FROM 
  OPENROWSET(
    'MSDASQL', 
    'Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt;*.csv)};DefaultDir=PATH_TO_DIRECTORY_HOLDING_FILE;Extensions=csv;',
    'select * from NAME_OF_CSV_FILE.csv'
  ) csv;
```

Comment: For BULK INSERT i must have table in the database with the structure, I want to get the csv file thought FileDialog and directly import to Database with its structure and data.

Alternatively I can extract the first line from CSV file to create the structure and adding the rows with loop manually, but i wonder if i can achieve something with access without any hard coding how come it is possible that there will be no way to perform the same task with SQL server database.